# How to install and use Roomba_500_series stack?

Tags: ros, roomba-500-series

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no tutorials for this stack but I would like to know what it does and how to install.

I have turtlebot installed on a laptop connected to a Roomba with a serial SCI.  My first step is to get teleop going.  Help please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11219/how-to-install-and-use-roomba_500_series-stack?/) by [kleekru](https://answers.ros.org/users/987/kleekru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The stack is actually called `roomba_robot` and `roomba_500_series` is a package in it. You just need to check out the stack repository and add the directory to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. The repository seems to be an SVN repository, so you can get it by:

```
svn co http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/unstable/roomba_robot
```

I actually prefer using rosinstall for managing my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. To use it, you can install/update rosinstall by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install -U rosinstall
```

Then create a rosinstall file for roomba_robot:

```
roslocate info roomba_robot > ~/roomba-robot.rosinstall
```

Now create an overlay of your rosinstallation with `roomba_robot` added:

```
rosinstall ~/ros_roomba /opt/ros/electric ~/roomba-robot.rosinstall
```

Now edit your `~/.bashrc` and replace the line

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
```

by

```
source ~/ros_roomba/setup.bash
```

Make sure to open a new terminal or execute the above `source` command by hand. Now you should be able to `rosmake roomba_500_series`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kleekru](https://answers.ros.org/users/987/kleekru/) on 2011-09-16**:
Previous to the message above I received an error creating the "build" directory as part of the make for cereal_port package.  Then I manually added the build directory and tried to run a rosmake on the cereal_port package by itself and received the errors above.  Please please please help.  It seems like the roomba should be working... I think I'm missing something simple.

**Comment by [kleekru](https://answers.ros.org/users/987/kleekru/) on 2011-09-16**:
I created the "build" directory in the cereal_port package directory and tried running rosmake only on cereal_port and recieved this new error:       {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/isr-uc-ros-pkg/lse_communication/cereal_port/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:22 (FILE):
file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/isr-uc-ros-pkg/lse_communication/cereal_port/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
for writing.
Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMake Error: Failed to create CMakeList file for /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/isr-uc-ros-pkg/lse_communication/cereal_port/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:42 (FILE):
file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/isr-uc-ros-pkg/lse_communication/cereal_port/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
for writing.
Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:50 (MESSAGE):
The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

```
It fails with the following output:

 



CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/isr-uc-ros-pkg/lse_communication/cereal_port/build/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied

[ rosmake ] Output from b

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-06**:
@Lorenz Very nice ! everything works nicely - but what do I do next ? I have a very basic roomba 561 - no laser - may use ASUS Xtion later. What do I do next to get this moving. I am on ROS Electric.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you go to the roomba_500_series webpage you'll notice under dependencies that you also need cereal_port, meaning you'll need to download both roomba_robot and serial_communication stacks.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roomba_robot

http://www.ros.org/wiki/serial_communication

You can do that using svn as suggested earlier into a folder on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, do not download them into your ROS installation stacks folder!!! Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/lse_roomba_toolbox/Tutorials/Installing%20the%20software%20for%20a%20Roomba) I wrote on how to install the software for a Roomba netbook. You can edit the rosinstall file there to meet your requirements. It was created for our lab Roombas so your probably don't need some of the stacks there.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3